# Get Entries in Parted

Tags: scripting, parted

I was determined to solve this myself but after much frustration here I am. I am trying to get the entries in `parted` for a particular disk.

I can do something like this

```
parted /dev/sdc print
```

but I would like to return just the details of each partition for this disk, without the header information, i.e.

```
1      1049kB  535MB   534MB   primary  ext3         boot, type=83
...
```

Comment: That is indeed what it does. What did you want? Can you define “return each partition for this disk.”

Answer (score 4):

Ah. You just want the partitions themselves without the `parted` header. Here's one way of doing that:

```
# parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  15.6GB  15.6GB  primary  ext4
 2      15.6GB  16.1GB  489MB   primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

And

```
# parted /dev/sda print | awk '$1+0'
 1      1049kB  15.6GB  15.6GB  primary  ext4
 2      15.6GB  16.1GB  489MB   primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

The `awk` command looks at the first field on the line (`$1`), and if it's numeric and non-zero prints the entire line.